# LaTeX: how to use a required arg as the default for an optional one?

Tags: latex, definition, tex

I'm trying to create a LaTeX command with two arguments, one of them optional. Normally I'd do this as

```
\newcommand{\whatever}[2][default]{first #1 second #2}
```

where `default` is the default value for the first argument. But for this command I want the value of the second argument to be used as the default value for the first argument - that is, I want

```
\whatever{blah}
\whatever{foo}
\whatever[lol]{rofl}
```

to be equivalent to

```
\whatever[blah]{blah}
\whatever[foo]{foo}
\whatever[lol]{rofl}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? I can drop down to plain TeX if necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel has an inbuilt method of doing this, although it's not widely used. Here's an example:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@foo[2][]{[1: #1, 2: #2.] }
\newcommand\foo{\@dblarg\@foo}
\makeatother

\foo{same}
\foo[hello]{world}
```

Obviously, the `\makeatletter` commands can be dropped if you're doing this inside a `.sty` or `.cls` file.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly hack:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}

...

\newcommand{\whatever}[2][uniquenonesense]{
   ... 
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{uniquenonesense}}{#1}{#2}
   ...
}
```

Presumably you wanted something cleaner, but that's what I've got.

Depending on your semantics, `uniquenonesense` might be empty.

Comment: Works for me ;-) sure, clean would be nice, but I really just want something that gets the job done. It's less of a hack than a lot of other LaTeX code I've read...

Answer (score -1):

```
    \newcommand{\haha}[2]{\backslash whatever \left[ #1 \right] 
    \left[   #1     \right] }

    \begin{document}
    $\haha{blah}{blah}$\\
    $\haha{stupid}{Idiot}$
    \end{document} % This works very well.
```